# Simple ajax not working: begginner

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have this function that is called when a form is submitted. but its not working and my book is very vague and only shows how to retrieve data. could someone help me  error 0.

```
var formElement = document.getElementById("quizform");
var oData = new FormData(formElement);
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("post","http://www.cwu.edu/~janvik/CS250/echo.php",true);
xmlhttp.send(oData);    
  if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
  document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
} else {
   document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = "Error " + xmlhttp.status + " occurred uploading your file.<br \/>";
        }
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning the error code and maybe adding the PHP code as well.

Comment: the php does not have an error, it works with plain html and was written by my professor. it gives me code 0